# Problem with sorting for pagination in Meteor after viewing a document detail

Tags: reactjs, sorting, meteor, pagination

I've written server-side pagination for documents in Meteor 1.8.1; on my Home page you see a paginated list of documents. If you click on one of the 10 displayed documents, you navigate to the detail page for that document. The problem is that if you then click Home from the detail page, to return to the paginated list, the document which you just viewed appears at the top of the page, regardless of its name. For example if you view "B Document" then click Home, the list is:

B Document

A Document
...

I'm applying a client-side sort but nothing I have tried causes the recently-viewed document to appear in the correct place on the page. Only refreshing the Home page fixes the sort to show "A Document" first.

name_sort is a field I added for case-insensitive sorting, it is generated as `name.toLowerCase()` when the document is created.

Here's my publish.js:

```
Meteor.publish('documents', (skip = 0, limit = 10) => {
    return Documents.find({},
        {
            'fields': {
            'name': 1,
            'name_sort': 1,
        },
        'sort': { 'name_sort': 1 },
        'skip': skip,
        'limit': limit,
    });
});

Meteor.publish('document', function (_id = undefined) {

return Documents.find(
    { _id },
    {
        'fields': {
            'name': 1,
            'name_sort': 1,
        },
    },
);
```

});

And here's how my React Home page accesses the data:

```
const Tracker = withTracker(({ pageSkip, dispatch }) => {
    dispatch(setIsLoading(true));

    Meteor.subscribe('documents', pageSkip, 10, {
        'onReady': () => {
            dispatch(getDocumentCount());
            dispatch(setIsLoading(false));
        },
    });

    return {
        ''documents:': Documents.find({}, {
            'sort': { 'name_sort': 1 },
            'limit': 10,
        }).fetch(),
    };
})(Home);
```

Any idea how I can fix this? It must be something simple but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Update: I've got the sorting kind of working - I had forgotten to publish the name_sort field - but there is still a problem that the document I viewed in detail appears at the top of the list on the Home page, then it then either disappears or jumps into its correct place, depending on whether it should appear on this page. I guess this must be because the document is still in MiniMongo from before, and the list is only corrected when the new subscription is ready. It looks pretty bad if there is any kind of server lag.

What I'd like to do is clear MiniMongo when the Home page loads but I can't find a way to do that? I tried stopping the single-document subscription with `this.stop()` but that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to set a flag "isLoading" to true when the component subscribes to the publication, and set it to false when the subscription is ready. Then use this flag to hide the list of documents until the subscription is ready; this glosses over the awkward time when the document from the previous page is still in MiniMongo.